# Make a div scroll out to reveal main content which is placed below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to achieve the type of effect seen at Forde + Nichol - http://fordenicol.com/

I would like the initial div to scroll away and then reveal the main content below and be able to continue scroll down the page. I have looked at a variety of reveals and footer reveals that are available online but fixed height cause an issue when attempting to continue scroll through content.

https://jsfiddle.net/3gkazmb8/2/

HTML

```
<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="content">

<p>Content Information</p>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
 padding-bottom: 600px;
}
.overlay {
 height: 1200px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 background: red;
}

.content {
 height: 1800px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/);
 background-color: #000;
 z-index: 1;
}

.content p{
 color: yellow;
 font-size: 50px;
 padding-top: 500px;
}
```

This is the layout and general idea of how I want to achieve the effect but the fixed height and positions of the divs cause the content to be hidden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could always inspect how the page in question has do it :)

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are your attempts and what problems did you encounter with your attempt(s)....

Comment: Sorry all I've added the fiddle I've been working on

Comment: You can google parallax scrolling.i think that this is too complex for you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go,
Scroll Magic is an awesome plugin I have used in the past,

Use that with GSAP animation library and you will have smooth animations.

The tutorial is in the link I have attached
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally got there. Unfortunately it wasn't fully possible with CSS so had to revert to using the plugin Curtains to achieve the transition - http://curtains.herokuapp.com/

Thanks everyone for your replies!